# How to convert cell variable to classified variable inside of parfor loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I my using parfor loop in matlab, but I have faced with a case that I don't know how to resolve it.
I want to save the error of the computation in list called ***err_list***, but Matlab gives me an error. Would some one can help me to resolve this problem ?
Here is my code, everyrthing works fine, but error riase at last four lines of the code and tells me that, ***err_list*** is not classified.

```
err_list = cell(length(lambda1_list),2);

 parfor l1 = 1:length(lambda1_list) % over l1
            this_param = params;


        % Create this to save CV error:
        tmp=zeros(params.nfolds,1);

    for l2 = 1:length(lambda2_list)



        this_param.lambda1 = lambda1_list(l1);
        this_param.lambda2 = lambda2_list(l2);
        % Get Nth fold training and test data and compute CV error
        for Fold=1:size(Fold_indices,2)

        Y_train=y_train(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);
        Y_test=y_train(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

        N=size(Y_test,1);
        Dictionary_train=dictionary_train(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

       Dictionary_test=dictionary_train(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);


        [totBeta,theta,omega,rho,nu] = learn(Dictionary_train,Y_train, this_param);


       err = (1/N) * sum(sum(( Y_test- Dictionary_test * totBeta).^2));

       %err
       tmp(Fold,1)=err;
        totBeta




    end
       err_list{l1,1}=mean(tmp);
       err_list{l1,2}=[lambda1_list(l1),lambda2_list(l2)];
    % for loop  l2
end %
```

**Here is the error I get :**

```
Error: File: holdOutMethod.m Line: 111 Column: 8
The variable err_list in a parfor cannot be classified.
See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Overview".
```

Comment: Which line  is `Line: 111` stated in error?

Comment: err_list{l1,1}=mean(tmp);

Comment: I am not expert enough to point out the problem just by watching the code. So if you could provide a sample data along with the code that gives the above error for you. I can test it and suggest any corrections.

Comment: Try replacing the two assignments to err_list with a single one `err_list(l1,:) = {mean(tmp) [lambda1_list(l1),lambda2_list(l2)]}`

Comment: @random-guy is correct, _Fixed Index Listing_ condition must hold for `err_list`. The same issue is explained in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143784/error-during-parallel-processing-in-matlab/37145940#37145940)